# loading failed error when install R package from github

Tags: r, github, package

I am working on Bayesian inference and I want to install ***bayesVAR_TVP*** package from Github. I tried the following commands:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("GediminasB/bayesVAR_TVP")
```

and

```
install.packages("githubinstall")
gh_install_packages("bayesVAR_TVP")
```

In both case I received the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'bayesVARTVP' in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 DLL 'bayesVAR' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'bayesVARTVP' in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 DLL 'bayesVAR' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing 'C:/Users/Hamed/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/bayesVARTVP'
In R CMD INSTALL
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

I have checked some similar questions on this site but they could not help me.  I am working on a Win 7 64b and R 3.4.3. Also, my friend has a similar error on mac system. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You should only need to do `library(devtools); install_github("GediminasB/bayesVAR_TVP");`. Having said that, I can confirm your error. Perhaps it's best to raise an issue on the [GitHub project site](https://github.com/GediminasB/bayesVAR_TVP).